# how to make an easy graphical tool to combine database tables in vb.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

We have to combine 3 dinstinct sql databases into one. I've copied all tables into a single Database, and now I'd have to assign then toghether. the situation is this:

- the database has 3 Tables. Call them TB1 TB2 TB3
- each table has its own ID column
- each table contains different informations about the same item, except for the shelf property. for example, tb1 contains shelf, size and color, tb2 contains shelf, quantity and serial number, tb3 contains shelf, price and material
- a shelf can contain multiple items. So same shelf does not mean same item. But a single Item cannot be on 2 shelfes.
- the ID numbers of the tables do not match. so for example ID 30 of tb1 is not the same item as ID 30 on tb2.
- A item present in one table MIGHT not be present in other tables.
- each table contains about 1000 rows

What I need to do is to come up with a tool that allows the user to quickly create connections between tables. My current idea is to make a form with 3 Datagridviews one next to the other, containing the 3 databases. Then when I select a row on the first Datagridview it automatically scrolls to the rows in the other two datagridviews where the shelfnumber is the same. (if there is one..) the user selects one row in each table and hits the save Button, the three ID numbers of the single tables are saved into a new table.

But maybe there is a better solution to this. maybe something graphical? easier to use then selecting single rows in each table?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lack of a common Primary Key across the tables makes this difficult - as I'm sure you discovered.

I'd try something like this and see how it looks in the DGV

```
SELECT 'tb1' Table, ID, shelf, size, color, NULL QTY, NULL SN,     NULL Price, NULL Material from T1
UNION
SELECT 'tb2' Table, ID, shelf, NULL, NULL,  quantity,serial_number, NULL, NULL  from T2
UNION
SELECT 'tb3' Table, ID, shelf, NULL, NULL,  NULL,    NULL,         price,  material  from T3
```

You might be able to add a SORT BY  ID, Table to the bottom.

Each SELECT needs the same number of columns. Only the first SELECT is used for column headers.